# Update table while reading

Tags: sql, vb.net

I'm writing a piece of code (VB.NET) to cleanse a (quite big) table of data.

I am connecting to my SQL database, looping through the table, cleansing the data and adding the cleansed data in a different column.

As i'm currently doing an update to my database for each record in the same loop as where i am cleansing the data, i am wondering if there is a more efficient way of doing this, where i would cleanse the data and afterwards send all the updated records to the database in one go.

Simplified code:

```
'Connect
SQLConn.ConnectionString = strConnection
SQLConn.Open()
SQLCmd.Connection = SQLConn
SQLConn2.ConnectionString = strConnection
SQLConn2.Open()
SQLCmd2.Connection = SQLConn2

'Set query
strSQL = "SELECT Column1 FROM Table1"
SQLCmd.CommandText = strSQL

'Load Query
SQLdr = SQLCmd.ExecuteReader

'Start Cleansing
While SQLdr.Read
    Cleansing()

'Add to database
    strSQL2 = "UPDATE Table1 SET Clean_data = '" & strClean & "' WHERE Dirty_Data = '" & SQLdr(0).ToString & "'"
    SQLCmd2.CommandText = strSQL2
    SQLCmd2.ExecuteNonQuery() 
End While

'Close Connections
SQLdr.Close()
SQLConn.Close()
SQLConn2.Close()
```

I'm guessing (from searching for a solution) that it is possible to do the update outside of my loop, but i can't seem to find how to do it specifically.

Many thanks!

Comment: what does `cleasing` do?

Comment: Isn't the cleaning possible directly on DB?

Comment: during the cleansing i'm reformatting the data to clean up any invalid characters and have a consistent format

Comment: i could clean it directly on the DB, but i like to have more control over the process, so that i can have detailed feedback from the process, as well as log all details (also, im not very good with working inside an SQL DB)

Comment: but it is much better to leave it on the server as connection on the database needs higher cost.

Comment: give us an example of what you are trying to do.

Comment: I agree that it would be more efficient on the server, but since this does not need to happen frequently i don't mind this. I would still like to keep my code here as efficient as possible though :)

Comment: an example of what i am cleansing would be: a field which should contain '00000-000-00' --> cleaning all non-numeric characters, check length and putting it in the clean_data column (if the length is wrong, i skip it, and provide feedback in the log)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is taking a long time because the `update` is doing a full table scan for every record.  You can speed it up by adding an index on the column "Dirty Data".

Essentially, you are reading the data in the select statement.  Cleaning one row, and then updating it.  The preferred "set-based" approach is more like:
Ideally, you would like to do:

```
update table1
    set column1 = <fix the dirty data>
    where column1 <is dirty>
```

And you have some options in SQL, in terms of `replace()` and `case` and `like` (for instance) that can help with this process.

But you already have the cleaning code external to the database.  For this, you want to create and open a cursor, process the record, and then write back.  Cursors are relatively slow, compared to in-database operations.  But, this is *exactly* the situation they were designed for -- external code to be applied to individual records.

Comment: +1.  I agree that the SET based approach would be better than the procedural approach.  I use to use a procedural approach due to being less savvy with SQL.  I am a believer that you should do as much work at the database level as possible.  Though I can see why the OP wants to use the procedural approach (if logging is truely necessary), perhaps for future reference.

Comment: @w0051977 . . . The logging might not be necessary if the work were done in a single `update` statement.  After all, that is a single transaction so either all the work would be done or none.